# Is there any place where all current Mathematica bugs are listed?

Tags: bugs

It will be nice to be aware of bugs that the current version of Mathematica has. Is there any place where all current Mathematica bugs are listed?

Comment: [bugs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs) ?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk That is only a very inofficial and incomplete bug tracker.

Comment: see https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.datasets/stack_exchange_data/notebooks/bugList.html  generated by b3m2a1 in this answer:
https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2264/is-there-a-list-of-bugs-identified-by-the-mathematica-stackexchange There is no official such list, as commercial companies do not post list of bug in their software for many reasons.

Comment: Mathworks and MATLAB, on the other hand, have a very comprehensive search facility for all their bugs, if one has paid one's fees. I wish Wolfram could also have such.

Comment: @Nasser I'd say that these days the norm is to have user-viewable bug trackers for developer-facing commercial products (i.e. anything you would program in a computer language). Wolfram is falling behind here.